# MoviePy Not Properly Installed (Linux Mint 20)

Tags: pip, python-module, linux-mint, moviepy

I have run `pip3 install moviepy` simply to get the software installed. However I am unable to use it.

On a second run of pip I get:

`Requirement already satisfied: moviepy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.0.3)`

but I have no access to the attributes of moviepy. When I run `dir(moviepy)` I only get:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'version']
```

Have I done something wrong here, or is this to do with anything else I may have installed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/quick_presentation.html#example-code) you need to import the package like this:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

Comment: [that line](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/d213793576d03ff51fd835facf64c94e1a39075a/moviepy/__init__.py#L74) you mentioned is just overriding the behaviour of `import *` and seems it is not working, you can still access your desired class/function if you know the path. e.g. `from moviepy.editor import VideoClip`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install moviepy` installs the latest **stable** version from PyPI, currently it's [1.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/1.0.3/#history). [`__init__.py` for the version](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/v1.0.3/moviepy/__init__.py) is mostly empty, it doesn't import anything interesting. That what you see.

You need to import a [subpackage](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/ref.html) and run `dir()` on it:

```
import moviepy.video
print(dir(moviepy.video))
```